# Adding element to end of each sublist in the nested list

Tags: python-3.x

I've got a list:

```
list1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 9]]
```

I need the list to be updated by multiplying the two elements and added as third in the same list.

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 12], [7, 9, 63]]
```

Is this possible ?

Here is my code which doesn't do the job as expected -

```
    list1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 9]]

    for i in list1:
      print(i)
      digit1 = i[0]
      digit2 = i[1]
      final = digit1 * digit2

   list1.append(final)

   print(list1)
```

I tried this but didn't get the desired output-

Observed Output: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 9], 63]

Desired Output: [[1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 12], [7, 9, 63]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve this by using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 9]]

print([[x, y, x * y] for x, y in list1])
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 12], [7, 9, 63]]
```